# TypeError: row is undefined

Tags: javascript, row, undefined, typeerror

I need help with this JavaScript function I made. It works, but it always alerts me  with:

> "TypeError: row is undefined"

when I launch it.

Here is my code:

```
function checkRow(tableID){
        try{
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++){
        var row = table.rows[i];
        var id = row.cells[1].innerHTML;
            if(i != id){
            document.getElementById(tableID).rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML = i;
                }
            }

            }catch(e){
            alert(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in JavaScript are indexed starting at zero, not one.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
```

should help :-)

*edit* — oh and similarly, the "id" may need to be `row.cells[0].innerHTML` ...

Comment: I added this if(id != null && i != id) too in case